# Turn off specific monitors

Tags: display

Is there any way programatically or with some app to turn off specific monitors on commmand? Let's say I have 3 monitors, I want to turn 2 and 3 off/on on my command.

Answer (score 0):

Try Out the https://www.murgee.com/MurGeeMon/

Quoted from site:

> Enable / Disable Primary or Secondary Monitor
>
> Power of Monitor without looking for power buttons on Computer Monitor.
>   MurGeeMon allows you to control power of Secondary or All Monitors
>   connected to your computer. Secondary Monitor Power can be controlled
>   with a simple checkbox to enable / disable secondary monitor.

the download link is here https://www.murgee.com/MurGeeMon/download/setup.exe

Comment: This only works to disable/enable other monitors, which is an issue since everything on those gets moved to the 1st one if you disable them.

Comment: So do you want to have a missing monitor type of effect.

Comment: I want to turn them off/on in the way Windows does when computer is idle.